# How to avoid the null values in String array in java..?

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
String[] m_cPackageName;

int m_size;

int j=0;

List<ApplicationInfo> installedList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
m_size = installedList.size();

m_cPackageName=new String[m_size];

for (PackageInfo pi : pkginfoList) {

    try {
        m_appinfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(pi.packageName, 0);
        if ((m_appinfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
        // equal to zoo means system apps, not equal is third party installed apps 
        m_cPackageName[j]=pi.packageName;

        j++;
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Name not found", e);
}
```

Here I'm getting total size of installedList is 56..After filling the value in array it display in null values. how can i eliminate  the null values.. Any one Help for me..

**OUTPUT :**

```
m_cPackageName=String[56];

m_cPackageName[0]="Myvalue"

m_cPackageName[1]="null"

m_cPackageName[2]="null"
.

.

.

m_cPackageName[55]="null"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less than `m_size` elements are being added to the array (of size `m_size`), which results in unassigned `null` elements at the end.

This is because *`j` is only increased sometimes* - inside a conditional (`(m_appinfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0`), and only when an exception is not thrown and caught.

A simple solution is to use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), then only add the "approved" elements. Because a List/ArrayList grows on demand, there are no trailing null (unassigned) elements as might be found in a fixed-size array.

```
// List, not array
List<String> m_cPackageName = new ArrayList<String>();

// ..
if ((m_appinfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
    // Only added to list sometimes, but m_cPackageName.size() is
    // always the count of elements that HAVE been added.
    m_cPackageName.add(pi.packageName);
}

// Then, if you really need an array, which will now be the proper size
// and not contain null elements because the size is computed based on the
// accepted elements in m_cPackageName which is m_cPackageName.size() ..
String[] arrayOfPackageNames = m_cPackageName.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

add null check before inserting element to array.

```
if ((m_appinfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
   if(pi.packageName!=null){
        m_cPackageName[j]=pi.packageName;
        j++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (((m_appinfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0)&& (pi.packageName != null &&!pi.packageName.equals("")) {
                         // equal to zoo means system apps, not equal is third party installed apps 
                          m_cPackageName[j]=pi.packageName;

                            j++;
                       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating the array based on the size of `installedList`, but you are iterating over `pkginfoList`.  A better way to do this is to create a `List<String> packageNames = new ArrayList<String>();`, and then add to that list in your loop.

That way, you don't have worry about counting or size.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((m_appinfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
  // equal to zoo means system apps, not equal is third party installed apps 
    if(pi.packageName!=null){
        m_cPackageName[j]=pi.packageName;
        j++;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please explain what you did

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to disambiguate empty and null strings, consider storing nulls as empty; something like this:

```
m_cPackageName[j]=pi.packageName == null ? "" : pi.packageName;
```

This might reduce the risk of things blowing up as NullPointerException-s further down.